# How to sum int random number and double random number?

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    System.out.println(randomNumber.nextInt(10));
    Random randomNumberTwo = new Random();
    System.out.println(randomNumberTwo.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(randomNumber + randomNumberTwo);
```

The terminal says: java: bad operand types for binary operator '+'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad operand types for binary operator '>' using doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101737/bad-operand-types-for-binary-operator-using-doubles)

Answer (score 1):

randomNumber and randomNumberTwo are generators, so in order to add them you need to generate the next value from them:

```java
Random randomNumber = new Random();
Random randomNumberTwo = new Random();
System.out.println(randomNumber.nextInt(10) + randomNumberTwo.nextDouble());
```

Comment: I suggest using only one generator as well - two generators is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are adding the objects of the class random numbers instead to this

```
  Random randomNumber = new Random();
   int a = randomNumber.nextInt(10)
    System.out.println(randomNumber.nextInt(10));
    Random randomNumberTwo = new Random();
    double b = randomNumberTwo.nextDouble()
    System.out.println(randomNumberTwo.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(a + b);
```